# Pandas - Split column of strings of length 3 into 3 columns for each character

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this Series data that can look like this

```
1         532
2         554
3         525
...       ... 
Name: score, Length: 941940, dtype: str
```

I'd like to split it on each character so that it becomes 3 columns so for example it should look like this after

```
        score_0  score_1  score_2
1       5          3        2
2       5          5        4     
3       5          2        5          
...     ...        ...      ...
[941940 rows x 3 columns]
```

I tried using the `split` function by Pandas but it only splits on whitespaces if you don't set the delimiter and I don't know what to set it for to split on every character.

Ideally it should name the columns as "_" and also should just change `nan` rows to being a row of 3 empty values for the new columns.

Comment: You don't need `split`.  Calling `list('555')` results in a list of three one-character strings.

Comment: @TimRoberts but I have to apply this to the entire column and generate new columns with names in format "<column_name>_<index>"

Comment: @BigBen almost! Is there a way to name to columns by "<original column name>_<index>"?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(ser.agg(list).tolist()).add_prefix("scores_")` ? (*with* `ser` *your input Series*).

Comment: I added something else to the question. Which is that is should support `nan` values.

Comment: @Timeless your suggestion threw "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'"